# How to add content before page content is displayed in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to add a block of code before the content of the page is included in Wordpress.
However adding:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'custom_function' );
```

doesn't work as it add it between the title and the content and

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_function' );
```

adds it in places like the title of the page where I dont need it.

Isn't there something like??

```
add_filter( 'before_page', 'custom_function' );
```

Comment: Would it be the same content on each page or different content?

Comment: I use if(is_front_page())
Cause it is a block that has to be show first thing only in the homepage.

Comment: Is it a normal page or have you it set as a front page template?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do really depends on the theme. Some themes, like Genesis, have them, some don't. To see if yours does check for add_action on the template page.

You can also diy by [adding an action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) to your theme yourself. Wherever you need the content inserted pop in `add_action('before_page');` and you'll have your action in place.